# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Xcode practice

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Xcode is not throwing any errors until I build the app in the simulator. As soon as the simulator launches it triggers the SIGABRT error. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var cellContent = ["example"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellContent.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: In with line the SIGABRT error happened?

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like the error was in AppDelegate:

Comment: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: A SIGABRT means the signal between the simulator and your code has been abrupted. Check all your code connections with you UI elements. Normally the stack trace can show more information where the problem happened as well

Comment: Oh good to know! Thanks! I'll check it out and see what I can find

Comment: If you past the call stack in your question I will be able to tell you what component is the one with the disconnection.

Comment: Sorry for the question, I'm VERY new to programming. What is the call stack or where would I find it?

Comment: Hopefully this is what you're talking about:

libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x10b5c327c <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
    0x10b5c3281 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10b5c3284 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10b5c3286 <+10>: jae    0x10b5c3290               ; <+20>
    0x10b5c3288 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10b5c328b <+15>: jmp    0x10b5bec53               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x10b5c3290 <+20>: retq   
    0x10b5c3291 <+21>: nop    
    0x10b5c3292 <+22>: nop    
    0x10b5c3293 <+23>: nop

Comment: SIGABRT occurs on 0x10b5c3286